# Flushing in integration test

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, spock

I am trying to write an integration using Spock but I am struggling with hibernate as I have a special scenario. This is basically the scenario:

I have a method in a service that summarise some info from a table. This service connects with the database using the class groovy.sql.Sql

```
def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
sql.execute("insert into summary_table .... values from content_table")
```

Then, in the integration test, first of all I am inserting random data in the content table using the build-test-data plugin, using the GORM method save()

The tests works fine sometime but others, it seems like all the data in content_table has not been fully populated when summarising data and some rows are missing (not all of them, only a few).

This is basically the test:

```
def "this is my failing test"() {
   given:
      100.times {
          ContentTable.build().save()
      }
   when:
       def results = myservice.summarisingContentTable()
   then:
       results.size() == 100
}
```

The then block is more complicated but I think it will serve to explain the problem.

I think the problem is related to hibernate and when the transaction should be commited. Can somebody help me with this?

**UPDATE**: I have just set up a breakpoint before running myservice.summarisingContentTable() and tried next queries with different results sometimes, so the ContentTable is populated properly.

```
ContentTable.count()//returns the proper value
sql.execute("select count(*) as total from content_table").total //returns sometimes the proper value - 1, so one content_table record is missing
```

Comment: not sure how you build the `ContentTable`... did you check `ContentTable.build().save()` not returning `null` to make sure there is no error in the built object?

Comment: ContentTable is being populated properly. I am debugging with IntelliJ IDEA and some break points and it has the proper value, but for any reason when calling the method service, sometimes this table does not have the full contents.

Comment: Out of couriosity: when it fails, does it fail by one?  or is it just a random number?

Comment: It usually fails just one record, which is driving even more crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your ContentTable is properly created ? In my tests, I use this idiom:

```
assert myObject.save() || myObject.errors.allErrors.empty
```

that way, it prints instantly what the errors were, if any.

Secondly, if you're using the newest Grails 2.4, then please bear in mind that they don't autoflush by default. Check the documentation how to change it, or save(flush:true).

Comment: Yes, they are properly created. I think the problem is with flushing properly using hibernate.

Comment: One of the techniques I use in cases where I can't think of a good reason involves debugging deep down through the entire hibernate save(flush:true) call. I found once for example that hibernate would quietly ignore some of the properties because they weren't properly mappedBy, which gave them some indicator that later made hibernate ignore them by some if(). It does take a while, but it's very powerful and can uncover one's bugs as well as undocumented or even buggy behaviour of grails.